# relation between the convolution and multiplication of polynomials: interesting formula

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials, convolution

Recently I figured out that:

$f*g \equiv fg \mod x^{n}-1$

Is there something interesting about this relation between the convolution and multiplication of polynomials?

Comment: What is $n$ in the equation?

Comment: $n-1$ is the degree of the polynomial

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what you figured out ( the method you used to derive the result you stated. maybe it will help people answer your question by understanding where it came from).